# Find duplicates formula is ignoring punctuation marks

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, I'm finding duplicates using the common approach of:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>1,"Duplicate","Unique")
```

But it is ignoring punctuation marks like '?'

For example, if I have 'wordA' and 'wordA?' it shows them as duplicates when they are not.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: I have tested your formula and it worked on my side. Can you share a sample spreadsheet so that we may replicate the issue you encountered?

Comment: Unfortunately can't share it as contains sensitive data, but in trying to create a non-sensitive version for you I discovered that the formula does indeed work with punctuation except for 1 specific row (out of approx 10k). Very weird but I can live with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `countif()` function treats `?` as a wildcard that matches any single character. `wordA?` will match `wordA`  that has a trailing space. To get exact matches only, use `filter()`, like this:

`=if( counta(iferror(filter(A:A, A:A = A2))) > 1, "Duplicate", "Unique" )`

See [countif()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093480).

Comment: Thanks for this. I understand what's going on now and your formula works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(COUNTIF(A:A&"×", A2&"×")>1, "Duplicate", "Unique"))
```

[image]